# How to add test unit in js

Tags: javascript

```
let number = 64.129922
console.log(number - 10); //here i need only minus last 2 

console.log(number - 10); //here i need only
```

le.log(number - 10); //here i need only minus last 2

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't be in the position of needing to convert `10` to `.00001` based on the perceived number of places-after-the-decimal in the first number, not least because numbers have no intrinsic places-after-the-decimal concept. One moment it could be 3, the next 7, depending on the value. What is the underlying X problem?

Comment: Don't worry i need only to from whole number substract -10 but last two number.

Comment: Crowder I need to move the latitude -10 every next one. means to be below the pin. So if he is now 11.123456 the next one must be the last 2 decimal places by 10 less.
 @T.J.Crowder

Comment: You're missing the point. `40` is a valid latitude. So are `40.1`, `40.12`, `40.123`, etc. The `number` type has no concept of how many places there are after the decimal. `40` and `40.000000` are **exactly** the same thing. So anything where your starting point is figuring out how many digits there are to the right of the decimal point of a number is going to fail. Instead, pick your precision and use it, e.g. subtract `.00001` rather than `10`, `.000001` instead of `1`, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes you are right. But how do I do that?

Comment: By doing that. Use `.0001` instead of `10`. Use `.000001` instead of `1`. If needed, with math (it's dividing by a million). Side note: `64.131577 - 76 = 64.131571` doesn't make any sense, it's closer to 64.131501.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reliably use the number of digits after the decimal in a number. The `number` type doesn't have any concept of how many digits are after the decimal (and the algorithm to determine how many to include when creating a string for the number is complex.

**If** you always want to adjust the values you're subtracting to turn `10` into `.00001` and `1` into `.000001`, etc., then what you're doing is dividing them by 1,000,000:

```js
function addAdjusted(base, addend) {
    return base + (addend / 1000000);
}

console.log(addAdjusted(64.131577, -10)); // 64.131567 (roughly)
console.log(addAdjusted(64.131577, -1));  // 64.131576 (roughly)
console.log(addAdjusted(64.131577, -76)); // 64.131501 (roughly)
```

Note that at those scales, the number type becomes [fairly imprecise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). If you're going to output the results as strings, you might consider using `toFixed(6)` to adjust the output:

```js
function addAdjusted(base, addend) {
    return base + (addend / 1000000);
}

console.log(addAdjusted(64.131577, -10).toFixed(6)); // "64.131567"
console.log(addAdjusted(64.131577, -1).toFixed(6));  // "64.131576"
console.log(addAdjusted(64.131577, -76).toFixed(6)); // "64.131501"
```